# c# wpf bind a list to an Listview - listview row is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I've an issue with binding data from a `List<>` to a `Listview` in WPF.
The `ListView` row is empty but the lists values are set in the `List<>`. If i do it with an `ListBox`, I see the values in one row.

Look at the code for the list:

```
 public static List<string> ShowUSB()
    {
        var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();
        List<string> Devices = new List<string>();
        foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
        {
            string[] DeviceIDs = usbDevice.DevicePNPDeviceID.Split(new Char[] { '\\', '&', '_' });
            usbDevice.DeviceVID = DeviceIDs[2];
            usbDevice.DevicePID = DeviceIDs[4];

            Devices.Add(usbDevice.DeviceManufacturer + usbDevice.DeviceName + usbDevice.DeviceVID + usbDevice.DevicePID); 

        }

        return Devices;
    }
```

Here is the XAML code for binding:

```
   <GroupBox Header="available Devices" Margin="1,223,1,75"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <ListView x:Name="lvAddedDevices" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="colManufacturer" Width="240" Header="Manufacturer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DeviceManufacturer}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="colDeviceName" Width="240" Header="Device Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="colPNPVID" Width="200" Header="VID ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DeviceVID}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn x:Name="colPNPPID" Width="200" Header="PID ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DevicePID}"/>
                                <!--<GridViewColumn x:Name="colDeviceStatus" Width="200" Header="Device Status"/>-->
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>

                </GroupBox>
```

And the binding call in the code behind:

```
   internal void LoadDevicesforList()
    {

        lvAddedDevices.ItemsSource = USBHandler.ShowUSB();
    }
```

Here is the complete class:

```
public class USBHandler
{

    public static List<string> ShowUSB()
    {
        var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();
        List<string> Devices = new List<string>();
        foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
        {
            string[] DeviceIDs = usbDevice.DevicePNPDeviceID.Split(new Char[] { '\\', '&', '_' });
            usbDevice.DeviceVID = DeviceIDs[2];
            usbDevice.DevicePID = DeviceIDs[4];

            Devices.Add(usbDevice.DeviceManufacturer + usbDevice.DeviceName + usbDevice.DeviceVID + usbDevice.DevicePID); 

        }

        return Devices;
    }

    static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
    {
        List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

        ManagementObjectCollection collection;
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_PnpEntity where Manufacturer Like 'ATMEL%' or Manufacturer Like 'Microchip%' or Manufacturer Like 'Texas%' "))
            collection = searcher.Get();
        if (collection.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var device in collection)
            {

                devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID")
                ));

            }
        }

        collection.Dispose();
        return devices;
    }
}

class USBDeviceInfo
{
    public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceManufacturer, string deviceName, string devicePNPDeviceID)
    {
        DeviceManufacturer = deviceManufacturer;
        DeviceName = deviceName;
        DevicePNPDeviceID = devicePNPDeviceID;
    }
    public string DeviceManufacturer { get; private set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; private set; }
    public string DevicePNPDeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string DeviceVID { get; set; }
    public string DevicePID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect all the DisplayMemberBindings to work when the ItemsSource collection elements are only strings? You probably wanted to assign a `List<USBDevice>` to the ItemsSource property.

Comment: I think if you change this line `List<string> Devices = new List<string>();` to this `List<CORRECT_TYPE_HERE> Devices = new List<CORRECT_TYPE_HERE>();` you'll be on the right path at least.

Comment: Hi, the values are strings only :-(

Comment: What do you mean? When you write `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DevicePID}"` there has to be a public property `DevicePID` in the item type. `string` doesn't have such a property. Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview)

Comment: Hi Clemens,
i'm sorry i can't show you the complete class in this edit window... she's too long...

Comment: I will edit my question...

Comment: I think your `public static List<string> ShowUSB()` should probably return a list of whatever type GetUSBDevices() returns. You're returning a list of strings and hoping for them to be objects.

Comment: Sure @Jonny, two people did already say that...

Comment: @Clemens, yes but in a way that clearly was not understood

Comment: Grizzly, if your class is too big to fit in the edit window, then make a minimal complete and verifiable example. Isolating your code to be only about THAT problem will help you (or us) solve it

Comment: @Patrice OP was talking about the comment field. Then they decided to edit the question instead.

Comment: @clemens maybe. I'd say the wording was unequivocal, but whatever (I do see how the actions that have been made on the post prove me wrong though). It doesn't really change much of my point about the need for an mcve. That class doesn't look to be minimal to reproduce the issue at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ShowUSB` method to this:

```
public static List<USBDeviceInfo> ShowUSB()
{
    var devices = GetUSBDevices();

    foreach (var device in devices)
    {
        var deviceIDs = usbDevice.DevicePNPDeviceID.Split('\\', '&', '_');
        device.DeviceVID = deviceIDs[2];
        device.DevicePID = deviceIDs[4];
    }

    return devices;
}
```

Or even better, drop the whole method and change the `USBDeviceInfo` constructor to this:

```
public USBDeviceInfo(
    string deviceManufacturer, string deviceName, string devicePNPDeviceID)
{
    DeviceManufacturer = deviceManufacturer;
    DeviceName = deviceName;
    DevicePNPDeviceID = devicePNPDeviceID;

    var deviceIDs = devicePNPDeviceID.Split('\\', '&', '_');
    DeviceVID = deviceIDs[2];
    DevicePID = deviceIDs[4];
}
```

Then make the `GetUSBDevices` method public and directly call

```
lvAddedDevices.ItemsSource = USBHandler.GetUSBDevices();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Clemens, but now i get an compiler error:

`Severity Code Description Project file line suppression state
Error CS0050 Inconsistent Access: Return Type "List <USBDeviceInfo>" is less accessible than method "USBHandler.ShowUSB ()". `

Comment: Make it `public class USBDeviceInfo`

Comment: Hi Clemens, now i've tried your post, but i dont get an Member in
`lvAddedDevices.ItemsSource=USBHandler.GetUSBDevices`

Comment: Thanks a lot, now everything works well...
you are the best!